# ImportError: cannot import name 'OrderDetailView' from 'core.api.views' in Django and ReactJs

Tags: python, django, reactjs

after i Build OrderDetailView Class,

i run `python manage.py migrate` in backend
it show error as

> from .views import (
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'OrderDetailView' from 'core.api.views' (C:\Users\Dell\project7\core\api\views.py)

In frontend, it show an error as `Network Error`

> "message":"Network Error","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Network Error\n at >createError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:1970:15)\n at XMLHttpRequest.handleError

api > urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    ItemListView,
    AddToCartView,
    OrderDetailView
)
urlpatterns = [
    path('product-list/', ItemListView.as_view(), name='product-list'),
    path('add-to-cart/', AddToCartView.as_view(), name='add-to-cart'),
    path('order-summary/', OrderDetailView.as_view(), name='order-summary')
]
```

api> views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView, RetrieveAPIView
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_200_OK, HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
from core.models import Item, OrderItem, Order
from .serializers import ItemSerializer, OrderSerializer


class ItemListView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    queryset = Item.objects.all()

    class OrderDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
        serializer_class = OrderSerializer
        permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

        def get_object(self):
            try:
                order = Order.objects.get(
                    user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                return Response({"message": "You do not have an active order"}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

constants.js

```js
const localhost = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";

const apiURL = "/api";

export const endpoint = `${localhost}${apiURL}`;

export const productListURL = `${endpoint}/product-list/`;
export const addToCartURL = `${endpoint}/add-to-cart/`;
export const orderSummaryURL = `${endpoint}/order-summary/`;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view is need to change as.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView, RetrieveAPIView
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_200_OK, HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
from core.models import Item, OrderItem, Order
from .serializers import ItemSerializer, OrderSerializer


class ItemListView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    queryset = Item.objects.all()

class OrderDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self):
      try:
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
      except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return Response({"message": "You do not have an active order"}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: This was unnecessarily edited! Original answer points to indentation problem. The edit doesn't tell what the issue is.